# Using a switch in a do..while loop, in C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, do-while

A simple programm that reads strings, and responds using a switch;

in this do-while loop containing a switch, I am able to run case 1-4 with no issues, but once i hit the default case, the programme simply loops the default case over and over again the code is as follows;

```
    do {    switch ( switchstring (entry, input) )
/*the switchstring function is one 1 wrote to convert a given entry(string), 
into an input(integer)*/   
    {
    case 1:
        //code
        repeat = 2;
        break;
    case 2:
        //code
        repeat = 2;
        break;
    case 3:
        //code
        repeat = 2;
        break;
    case 4:
        //code
        repeat = 2;
        break;
    default:
        //code
        repeat = 1;
        break;}} while(repeat == 1);
```

the 2nd question is regarding my switchstring() function; is there a way to change the switch function such that it reads;

```
    case (insert string):
```

i.e. so that I can remove the entire switchstring() function

thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think the result of `repeat = 1;` ought to be?

Comment: There could be numerous problems, depending on the code you're not showing here.  The problem you're describing can't be reproduced.

Comment: I don't see any code that changes the value of `entry` or `input`. How will the return value of `switchstring` change in the `do-while` loop?

Comment: I realize the issue was that I left the ability to change the value of entry outside the loop, hence the constant repetition

@R Sahu, I used an if/else statement to turn string inputs such as BMI to 1.

Comment: @PerfLearner, it sounds like you have enough to solve your problem. It's always good to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question. Many times you will find the cause of the problem in the process of doing that.

Comment: @R Sahu, ok noted. and thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Show us how `switchstring (entry, input)` works.

The problem you are facing is because, in `default` you do the following:

```
repeat = 1;
```

Which makes `while(repeat == 1)` always `true`. And then `switchstring (entry, input)` always return something that makes your `switch` block always go the the `default case` again.

Comment: `repeat` could be changed again, within that loop.

Comment: hmm, but the OP did not mentioned how `switchstring (entry, input)`. :(

Comment: @DrewDormann, I think `switchstring (entry, input)` always return somthing that trapped into `default case` in the `switch` block. I edited my answer. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: @rakeb.void my bad, maybe I should have divided my questions into seperate posts.

Anyway thanks to ur hint, i realize it was because I left the ability for the programme to change `entry` inside the do-while loop.

Answer (score 0):

1. When no case will be true in switch, then it will go in default case of switch and you are specifying repeat=1; in default. After that while condition will be checked and it will be true because repeat is 1, again it will go to do and check condition, your switch function will return something and it will go to default.
2. To solve 2nd question regarding your switchstring() function, you have to show your code what you are doing in that function, So that i can give you best suggestion.

Comment: Actually, i left that part of the code out, as the goal was to eliminate the function; example. instead of writing 'case 1: //code; break; case 2:' etc. it would become 'case monday: //code; break; case tuesday:' or something along those lines

Comment: I hope, now you got the solution. If not then elaborate more and give me code of "switchstring" function. So that i can give you best answer.